# Какая структура данных подходит лучше, чтобы подсчитать вхождения подстрок?

Tags: c++, stl

Задача: из логов выдернуть все URI, по ним посмотреть самые популярные домены и пути.

Дергать URI из логов уже научился, разбивать их на отдельные части тоже. Осталось придумать как лучше в рамках STL составить рейтинги популярности доменов и путей, какие структуры использовать.

Comment: Какое-нибудь префиксное дерево?

Comment: Мне кажется - `map<string,int>`

Comment: Берете домен, вычисляете какое количество раз он встречается, используете std::map<std::string, int>, условие сортировки по второму типу в мапе (int).

Comment: Я бы наверное завел пару контейнеров типа `unordered_map` с ключем в виде домена и пути. И поддерживал бы их синхронность.

Comment: Вопрос типа "что лучше" должен оцениваться по конкретным критериям. Иначе это "основано на мнениях" и следует закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос именно в том как быстро и красиво подсчитать кол-во вхождений домена, учитывая что файл логов может быть очень большим и скорее всего читать его придется по кускам, а не просто затолкнуть в std::string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удобнее всего использовать `map<string, int>` (ассоциативный массив). Мою задачу получилось решить так:

1) Подсчитать рейтинги доменов/путей:

```
std::map<std::string, int> hosts;   
std::map<std::string, int> paths;

/* ... */

http::url url = http::ParseHttpUrl(uri);
++hosts[url.host];
++paths[url.path];
```

2) std::map нельзя отсортировать по значениям, но можно взять максимальный элемент через std::max_element(). Для составления топа выбираем N максимальных.
*Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370945/c-help-finding-the-max-value-in-a-map*

Comment: Контейнер <map> является отсортированным массивом, но сортировка произведена по ключу (строке в данном случае). Кроме как `std::max_element()`, `map<string, int>` можно отсортировать через `map<int, string>`, но тогда может не сохранится лексикографический порядок.